# Bypass simple JavaScript XSS Filter

Tags: javascript, security, filter, xss

this is for my studies in cs class - security:

can anyone tell me how to bypass this Function in order to get a "real" > outputted? the html entity works but isn't recognized as the end of the injected tag.

```
function escape_str(str) { return str.replace(/"|'|<|>|charCode/ig, ''); }
```

The input is delivered via
`name = prompt("How is your name");`
and spitted out into a h1 tag

Comment: Surely the whole point of homework is for you to figure it out yourself?

Comment: yeah sure but I am not getting the point :(